# Nginx - TooManyRedirects when removing trailing slashes and accessing folders

Tags: nginx, redirect

For our static content we added a redirect rule, to remove slashes at the end of those urls. That was done for seo reasons and worked fine. Now, we recognized, that when you try to access folders (which is not allowed), Nginx will automatically add a trailing slash to the url, which is then again removed by the redirect rule and you end up in a TooManyRedirects loop. How could we solve this?

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    aio threads=io_pool;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Remove `$uri/` from `try_files`

Comment: Removing $uri/ resulted in a 404 when I tried to access the my domain: www.myapp.com